# Easier way for users to launch my .NET-application (with Mono) on Mac OSX?

Tags: .net, macos, mono

I developed an application to run on Windows and Mac OSX.
Luckily it already runs quite well on both.

The only thing I don't like is that the user has to open the command prompt to launch my app.

Are there easier ways, like creating a desktop-shortcut, or even better creating a native dmg-file which installs Mono + my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an app bundle. The following instructions describe this for GTK# but should be easily adapted for any other GUI toolkit:

http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app

The app's launch script prompts the user to install Mono. Alternatively you could use the "mmp" tool included in the MonoMac addin for MonoDevelop, which can merge a subset of Mono into your app bundle.

You can find several guides to creating a dmg (e.g. http://el-tramo.be/guides/fancy-dmg) which is simply a disk image that contains your app, and has a nice background image and a shortcut to /Applications.